# What would be the consequences of a drastic reduction of Ukrainian and Russian exports?

Tags: ukraine, trade

In Spain, supermarkets have started limiting purchase of sunflower oil beyond 5 liters per person. It looks like there are supplying problems, since both Russia and Ukraine are the main exporters of this produce. This has immediately driven prices soaring. It has been mentioned that the same could happen with minerals that are critical for the automotive industry, such as xenon.

If Russia completes invasion of Ukraine, all exports could be restricted due to sanctions. Even if this outcome does not occur and the war lasts for some time, logistic problems would avoid exports.

Are there products mostly imported from Ukraine that cannot be substituted? Being in Spain we could use olive instead of sunflower oil (at an enormously higher price) but I guess it is not so easy to replace xenon in some applications.

And, what would be the consequences of lacking such products? Would car makers simply have to stop production, for instance?

Comment: Do you really need the word "forbidding" in the title?  That word suggests a boycott of Ukraine, but the body of the question seems more about the difficulty of exporting products.  You are probably going to get downvotes (not me) if you continue to use "forbidding".

Comment: Sorry, I am not an English native speaker and I couldn't find a synonym of _reducing to zero_. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Ukraine exports a wide variety of products that can be replaced by exports from other sources or other products. The impact could be very broad and you will need to narrow the focus down.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we generally do not handle questions on this site which ask us to make predictions for future events. The reason is that there is no way to prove who is wrong and who is right until those events actually happen, and then those answers aren't needed anymore.

Comment: Maybe focus less on the open ended “what would happen?” and ask more specifically about which goods, products, and services have Russian exports make up a significant amount of the global market

Answer (score 6):

In no particular order:

- [price of oil](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-60584798) (not the cooking variety) and probably natural gas too
- various steel-production derived [gasses](https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/ukraine-invasion-rattles-global-supply-chains/4015314.article) like neon, krypton, xenon etc. And
- palladium.

The gasses shortage would affect the semiconductors industry, already suffering  a crunch. Palladium is used in catalytic converters etc.

And besides sunflower, in the agri domain also [wheat](https://www.ft.com/content/e6a28dd9-ecea-4d67-b6b5-a50301b731b2); raw prices are already up like 50% since the invasion.